# Graph Theory in Lean

Tags: lean, lean4, lean-mathlib

I can't find an implementation of graph theory in Mathlib. Am I overlooking the file, or is it particularly difficult to do this, or has no one been interested in taking this on yet?

If it hasn't been done, what would be a good way to model the vertices of a graph? This seems to be the first crucial task, as once this is complete edges are easy to define, as are weights, vertex neighbors, etc. My general vision is that we should define types `Vertex` and have `VertexSet` be a set of types `Vertex`. Then `Edge` could be a 2-element set of types `Vertex` belonging to a particular `VertexSet`, and `EdgeSet` be a set of types `Edge`. `Graph` could extend typeclasses `VertexSet` and `EdgeSet`, I think.

But perhaps this is too difficult. Could `Graph` just be a typeclass with fields including a vertex set of `Nat`s, hence abusing the order of `Nat` to order vertices, and an edge set of 2-element sets of vertices? I'd appreciate any intuition on this matter from more-experienced engineers. I'm certain I'm overlooking something.

I'm also thinking about how to define `Graph` such that it can be extended to `Digraph`, `WeightedGraph`, etc. Adding weights could be an extension of `Graph` to include a `w : E -> Real`, where `E` is the edge set, as a new field. This would make it simple to call the weights, as well. How would we extend `Graph` to `Digraph`, which requires us to tag vertices in edges with `head` and `tail` somehow? I've considered adding functions `head` and `tail` mapping the edge set to the vertex set, but is there a way to require that these functions take values in the two vertices associated with the edge, or is this even necessary? Another idea would be that `Digraph` doesn't even need to extend `Graph` at all, and we could define it so that it's edge set is a set of pairs of vertices, so that we can call them separately. I'd also appreciate help thinking about this.

Comment: I'll let others give feedback on your proposed implementation (it's certainly a good exercise to write one yourself), but here is the main implementation which you had trouble finding: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/Combinatorics/SimpleGraph/Basic.html

Comment: @macbeth oh nice they have embeddings too

Comment: @macbeth is there support for digraph?

Comment: Not in mathlib (as far as I know), probably partly because in any given application it's easier to use the trick of identifying with a matrix of booleans rather than to get sidetracked into developing a full theory.

Comment: But coincidentally I remember Alex Best and Peter Nelson discussing an API for digraphs just last week -- you could ask them about it on the Lean Zulip if you are interested.

Comment: @macbeth Alternatively it sounds tedious to extract information from the matrix, but perhaps that's my inexperience talking.

Comment: @macbeth I'll give them a question about it.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it would be pretty fun and pretty efficient to implement a Graph library on top of AC-sets following [AlgebraicRewriting.jl](https://algebraicjulia.github.io/AlgebraicRewriting.jl/dev/)'s lead. Lots of work though... But might be possible to leverage MathLib.

Comment: I’d be interested - could we work on this together?

Comment: @hmltn I don't really understand Category Theory behind AC-sets and Algebraic Rewriting, and I'm not familiar with Mathlib, thus I'm of little help. :) Besides, I won't have free time at least until August. I'd advise against waiting for me before starting the project. :)

Comment: Don't count me out! @hmltn I'd like to work on this too

Comment: @AlexByard Please contact me at my email hmltn-2@proton.me or, I would prefer, join me on Discord, where I collaborate with ppl: https://discord.gg/rhVtxdJA , or any channels on my SE profile like Twitter or Patreon. I am ready to begin work, with you. Thank you.

Comment: @hmltn I joined the discord under the name K10. Send me a message and we can start to work!

Comment: You can also implement graph theory in such a way that complementation is built into the graphs, and digraph, simple graph, etc. are natural graph extensions. Working on this approach right now as well.

Comment: I was late - apologies - but you’re added ✅ I for now will be exploring basic predicate logic, being new to Lean, and will explore basic category theory next, which can bring me into epistemic graphs. 