# Lean proofs for graph algorithms

Tags: lean, lean4, graphs

I am new to lean but am interested in proving correctness of graph algorithms.  Is there a repository/website that talks about a proof using lean of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm, for example?

Comment: Perhaps [Kementzey's Bachelor of Science thesis](https://lean-forward.github.io/pubs/kementzey_bsc_thesis.pdf) is a good place to start, regarding graph representation and search.  See also this [closely related Question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/graph-theory-in-lean).

Comment: Sec. 4.2 of the above thesis describes shortest path finding by Dijkstra's algorithm.